# Changing maps colours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

So I am trying to change colours on my maps `ggplot` plot

the code is down below:

I am familiar with a `scale_fill_viridis_d()` function and also argument `options` in that function

However is there a way how to make those maps in "nicer" colours, I know that you don't know what "nicer" means but somewhat similar to example I attached?

Also I can write colours list "manually" but what if we have 100 or more countries?

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
require(maps)
require(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(spdep)

some.eu.countries <- c(
  "Portugal", "Spain", "France", "Switzerland", "Germany",
  "Austria", "Belgium", "UK", "Netherlands",
  "Denmark")
# Retrievethe map data

map_data("europe")
some.eu.maps <- map_data("world", region = some.eu.countries) 

g = ggplot(some.eu.maps, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill="lightgray", colour = "white") 
g

# Region base centroid
region.lab.data <- some.eu.maps %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarise(long = mean(long), lat = mean(lat)) 

# Now plotting countries
g = ggplot(some.eu.maps, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes( group = group, fill = region), colour = "black", size = 1.2) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
print(g)
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two option:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# get number of groups
groups <- some.eu.maps %>% 
  pull(region) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  length()

# continuous color scale from red over green to orange
colors1 <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "green", "orange"))(groups) 
# discrete colour scale with red, grren, and orange
colors2 <- rep(c("red", "green", "orange"), length.out = groups)

g <- ggplot(some.eu.maps, aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes( group = group, fill = region), 
               colour = "black", size = 1.2) 

g + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors1)
g + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors2)
```

Comment: I guess, the `colorRampPalette` is a function of `dichromat` package in R and not in `RColorBrewer`, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dichromat/versions/1.1/topics/colorRampPalette